# Convert sql query to linq expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to select all Systems that are not in table Process_Systems by incoming process_Id in method, i have writen SQL but now i need LINQ.. Please help me
How to convert SQL query like this to LINQ:

```
  SELECT   *
   FROM     Systems
     WHERE    id NOT IN (
       SELECT systemid
        FROM   Process_Systems
       WHERE  processId = 4
     );
```

or this one (these are equal)

```
  SELECT   Systems.*
  FROM     Systems LEFT JOIN Process_Systems ps
    ON ps.systemId = Systems.id
  AND ps.processId = 4
  WHERE    ps.systemId IS NULL;
```

Comment: Please show us some effort. What have you tried?

Comment: I did edit of my question... Please look again.

Comment: [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: @James, At least the free version does not convert from `SQL` to `Linq`, only the other way around.

Comment: @Silvermind regardless, the OP can still experiment themselves and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from system in Systems
             where id != (from process_system in Process_Systems
                          where process_system.processId == 4
                          select process_system.systemid).First()
             select system;
```

Finally you'll got IEnumerable object. If I got your question.